# Best way to display items and related offers/details in mobile apps

Tags: iphone, mobile-application, multi-column

I am trying to think of a way to represent list of items along with their offers/details as shown in [this](http://www.theweb77.com/plan-details/) link in mobile apps. Please refer to 1st table. 2nd column contains numbers as well as some text.

Table/list is not a good option as per my opinion. What could be possibly good way to show such data on mobile phone?

**Note:** I am designing app for iPhone.

Comment: Why dont you add some mockups or wireframes of some of the designs you have come up with and then the community here can help you better

Comment: well i am a developer.. I don't have any mockup..

Comment: @EngrAnum If the answer was helpful and useful to you, it would be nice if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that the more UIViews your app has, the more complex it becomes. I agree with you, that a table may not be the most beautiful, engaging way of displaying data. Sometimes too much information presented at once, can take away from the experience.

What you'd like to do can definitely be handled within one view, without sacrificing space. The way I would approach this would be using expandable cells.

For example check out [Michael Wong's](http://dribbble.com/mizko) app list concept below:

[image]

The new Peek app on iOS also does something similar, that's both beautiful and engaging:

[image]

Last but not least, here's a couple of third party libraries that can help you easily implement these features (in no specific order):

[SKSTableView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/skstableview)

[JKExpandTableView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview)

[EMAccordionTableViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/emaccordiontableviewcontroller)

[UIExpandableTableView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uiexpandabletableview)